# Deleting a MediaLibrary file reference via ContentResolver: how to get the file's id?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver, media-library

from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925196/deleting-files-via-a-contentresolver-as-opposed-to-deleting-them-via-file-del) I understand that if I want to remove a reference for a (video) file from the media library, I can do this:

```
Uri videoUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
Uri itemUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(videoUri, mediaId);
getContentResolver().delete(itemUri, null, null);
```

what I miss is how to retrieve the `mediaId`.

For this file I have its path, filename, size, etc.

Any idea?

Comment: As a workaround, I found that I already had the id, because I always manually add the file that eventually I want to delete, in my app. So I store the id into a shared preference. But this is not the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here the answer, look at the method `getVideoIdFromFilePath`:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11603899/1865860