# Android: delete file trought a content uri

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, delete-file

My app is able to open and process certain files. So you can tap on such a file for example in a file manager, and my app will be offered to open it. The intent filter in the manifest file is set up something like this.

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

  <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

Reading and processing the file like this works fine:

```
Context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(getIntent().getData());
```

The issue is, that I want to delete the file after processing it. (If the user checks a checkbox for it) Users typically don't need the file anymore after opening it with my app.

Currently I am only able to do it if the file is provided to me as a file uri (starting with file://). In this case this code works fine:

```
new File(contentUri.getPath()).delete();
```

But I don't know how to delete the file if it is provided as a content uri. (starting with content://)

For example this returns null, and does nothing:

```
Context.getContentResolver().delete(getIntent().getData(), null, null);
```

Comment: Where are you getting the `Uri` from?

Comment: Have a look at DocumentFile::deleteFile().

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting files via a 'ContentResolver' as opposed to deleting them via 'file.delete()'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925196/deleting-files-via-a-contentresolver-as-opposed-to-deleting-them-via-file-del)

Comment: @CommonsWare That is the hard part, the uri can come from any app the user uses to pick the file to open.

Comment: @M. Tarek Yes basically a duplicate of that. But as I tried getContentResolver().delete() usually does not delete the file, so the answere the is not working for me.

Comment: "the uri can come from any app the user uses to pick the file to open" -- no, I mean programmatically. Something in your code is causing you to get this `Uri`. What is it? Part of your [mcve] should be how you get the `Uri` pointing to some content that you wish to delete.

Comment: @CommonsWare I added the manifest intent filter allowing any app to send the data. Then the "getIntent().getData()" in the activity gets the uri.

Answer (score 5):

I have solved this using the below code.

> DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(getApplicationContext(),fileUri ).delete();

This works fine. Try it.

Comment: I get Unsupported call: android:deleteDocument

Answer (score 0):

You have no reliable means of deleting this content. It is not your content, and for all you know, it is not technically possible for it *to* be deleted. Responsibility for deleting it lies with the application that invoked your `ACTION_VIEW` activity, not you.

If you want to be able to delete the content, invert the flow. On Android 4.4+, you could use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` to allow the user to pick a piece of content. Then, the `Uri` you get back may allow you to delete it using `DocumentFile`.

Comment: Do you think that the DocumentFile class provides any addition over
Context.getContentResolver().delete(getIntent().getData(), null, null); ?

Seems like a class to be used on the providers side, not on the receivers.

(I have seen apps solving the deletion somehow, deleting files they were provided I was not able to.)

Comment: @GáborDemkó: "Do you think that the DocumentFile class provides any addition..." -- only for a `Uri` derived through the Storage Access Framework (e.g., `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`). A `Uri` that you get by other means, such as your `<intent-filter>`, does not have to represent something that can be deleted, by any means.

Comment: @CommonsWare, 602k. How are you doing it? Six days ago 601k. A thousand points in a week. I have to work for that a year. It cannot only be by extensive informative answers i think. The rich get richer... ;-).